# build file compilation failed in cuda on ubuntu

Tags: python, compilation, theano-cuda

I am trying to execute [this](https://github.com/hunse/cuda-convnet2/tree/master/cudaconvnet/src) Github repository. When I run the [build.sh](https://github.com/hunse/cuda-convnet2/blob/master/build.sh) file, I get the following error:
gcc version is :gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 
nvidia-smi:NVIDIA-SMI 340.24     Driver Version: 340.24 
Nvidia geforce 820 with computability is 2.1.

```
rc/weight_acts.cu(1289): error: type name is not allowed

src/weight_acts.cu(1290): error: type name is not allowed

src/weight_acts.cu(1291): error: type name is not allowed

src/weight_acts.cu(1292): error: type name is not allowed

src/weight_acts.cu(1293): error: type name is not allowed

src/weight_acts.cu(1294): error: type name is not allowed

src/weight_acts.cu(1325): error: type name is not allowed

src/weight_acts.cu(1325): warning: expression has no effect

src/weight_acts.cu(1213): warning: expression has no effect
          detected during instantiation of "void conv_weight_acts_c_preload_pc_2_pt_4_f_3_r_32_c_3<B_Y,B_X,pixelCache,pixelsPerThread,filtersPerThread,preloadCases,numColors,scale,checkCaseBounds>(cudaTextureObject_t, cudaTextureObject_t, float *, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, float, float) [with B_Y=16, B_X=16, pixelCache=2, pixelsPerThread=4, filtersPerThread=3, preloadCases=32, numColors=3, scale=false, checkCaseBounds=false]" 
(2214): here

src/weight_acts.cu(1289): warning: expression has no effect
          detected during instantiation of "void conv_weight_acts_c_preload_pc_2_pt_4_f_3_r_32_c_3<B_Y,B_X,pixelCache,pixelsPerThread,filtersPerThread,preloadCases,numColors,scale,checkCaseBounds>(cudaTextureObject_t, cudaTextureObject_t, float *, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, float, float) [with B_Y=16, B_X=16, pixelCache=2, pixelsPerThread=4, filtersPerThread=3, preloadCases=32, numColors=3, scale=false, checkCaseBounds=false]" 
(2214): here

src/weight_acts.cu(1290): warning: expression has no effect
          detected during instantiation of "void conv_weight_acts_c_preload_pc_2_pt_4_f_3_r_32_c_3<B_Y,B_X,pixelCache,pixelsPerThread,filtersPerThread,preloadCases,numColors,scale,checkCaseBounds>(cudaTextureObject_t, cudaTextureObject_t, float *, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, float, float) [with B_Y=16, B_X=16, pixelCache=2, pixelsPerThread=4, filtersPerThread=3, preloadCases=32, numColors=3, scale=false, checkCaseBounds=false]" 
(2214): here

src/weight_acts.cu(1291): warning: expression has no effect
          detected during instantiation of "void conv_weight_acts_c_preload_pc_2_pt_4_f_3_r_32_c_3<B_Y,B_X,pixelCache,pixelsPerThread,filtersPerThread,preloadCases,numColors,scale,checkCaseBounds>(cudaTextureObject_t, cudaTextureObject_t, float *, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, float, float) [with B_Y=16, B_X=16, pixelCache=2, pixelsPerThread=4, filtersPerThread=3, preloadCases=32, numColors=3, scale=false, checkCaseBounds=false]" 
(2214): here

src/weight_acts.cu(1292): warning: expression has no effect
          detected during instantiation of "void conv_weight_acts_c_preload_pc_2_pt_4_f_3_r_32_c_3<B_Y,B_X,pixelCache,pixelsPerThread,filtersPerThread,preloadCases,numColors,scale,checkCaseBounds>(cudaTextureObject_t, cudaTextureObject_t, float *, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, float, float) [with B_Y=16, B_X=16, pixelCache=2, pixelsPerThread=4, filtersPerThread=3, preloadCases=32, numColors=3, scale=false, checkCaseBounds=false]" 
(2214): here

src/weight_acts.cu(1293): warning: expression has no effect
          detected during instantiation of "void conv_weight_acts_c_preload_pc_2_pt_4_f_3_r_32_c_3<B_Y,B_X,pixelCache,pixelsPerThread,filtersPerThread,preloadCases,numColors,scale,checkCaseBounds>(cudaTextureObject_t, cudaTextureObject_t, float *, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, float, float) [with B_Y=16, B_X=16, pixelCache=2, pixelsPerThread=4, filtersPerThread=3, preloadCases=32, numColors=3, scale=false, checkCaseBounds=false]" 
(2214): here

src/weight_acts.cu(1294): warning: expression has no effect
          detected during instantiation of "void conv_weight_acts_c_preload_pc_2_pt_4_f_3_r_32_c_3<B_Y,B_X,pixelCache,pixelsPerThread,filtersPerThread,preloadCases,numColors,scale,checkCaseBounds>(cudaTextureObject_t, cudaTextureObject_t, float *, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, float, float) [with B_Y=16, B_X=16, pixelCache=2, pixelsPerThread=4, filtersPerThread=3, preloadCases=32, numColors=3, scale=false, checkCaseBounds=false]" 
(2214): here

src/weight_acts.cu(1048): warning: expression has no effect
          detected during instantiation of "void conv_weight_acts_c_preload_pc_2_pt_2_f_4_r_32_c_3<B_Y,B_X,pixelCache,pixelsPerThread,filtersPerThread,preloadCases,numColors,scale,checkCaseBounds>(cudaTextureObject_t, cudaTextureObject_t, float *, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, float, float) [with B_Y=16, B_X=16, pixelCache=2, pixelsPerThread=2, filtersPerThread=4, preloadCases=32, numColors=3, scale=true, checkCaseBounds=false]" 
(2476): here

src/weight_acts.cu(1049): warning: expression has no effect
          detected during instantiation of "void conv_weight_acts_c_preload_pc_2_pt_2_f_4_r_32_c_3<B_Y,B_X,pixelCache,pixelsPerThread,filtersPerThread,preloadCases,numColors,scale,checkCaseBounds>(cudaTextureObject_t, cudaTextureObject_t, float *, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, float, float) [with B_Y=16, B_X=16, pixelCache=2, pixelsPerThread=2, filtersPerThread=4, preloadCases=32, numColors=3, scale=true, checkCaseBounds=false]" 
(2476): here

src/weight_acts.cu(1051): warning: expression has no effect
          detected during instantiation of "void conv_weight_acts_c_preload_pc_2_pt_2_f_4_r_32_c_3<B_Y,B_X,pixelCache,pixelsPerThread,filtersPerThread,preloadCases,numColors,scale,checkCaseBounds>(cudaTextureObject_t, cudaTextureObject_t, float *, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, float, float) [with B_Y=16, B_X=16, pixelCache=2, pixelsPerThread=2, filtersPerThread=4, preloadCases=32, numColors=3, scale=true, checkCaseBounds=false]" 
(2476): here

src/weight_acts.cu(1052): warning: expression has no effect
          detected during instantiation of "void conv_weight_acts_c_preload_pc_2_pt_2_f_4_r_32_c_3<B_Y,B_X,pixelCache,pixelsPerThread,filtersPerThread,preloadCases,numColors,scale,checkCaseBounds>(cudaTextureObject_t, cudaTextureObject_t, float *, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, float, float) [with B_Y=16, B_X=16, pixelCache=2, pixelsPerThread=2, filtersPerThread=4, preloadCases=32, numColors=3, scale=true, checkCaseBounds=false]" 
(2476): here

src/weight_acts.cu(1054): warning: expression has no effect
          detected during instantiation of "void conv_weight_acts_c_preload_pc_2_pt_2_f_4_r_32_c_3<B_Y,B_X,pixelCache,pixelsPerThread,filtersPerThread,preloadCases,numColors,scale,checkCaseBounds>(cudaTextureObject_t, cudaTextureObject_t, float *, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, float, float) [with B_Y=16, B_X=16, pixelCache=2, pixelsPerThread=2, filtersPerThread=4, preloadCases=32, numColors=3, scale=true, checkCaseBounds=false]" 
(2476): here

src/weight_acts.cu(1055): warning: expression has no effect
          detected during instantiation of "void conv_weight_acts_c_preload_pc_2_pt_2_f_4_r_32_c_3<B_Y,B_X,pixelCache,pixelsPerThread,filtersPerThread,preloadCases,numColors,scale,checkCaseBounds>(cudaTextureObject_t, cudaTextureObject_t, float *, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, float, float) [with B_Y=16, B_X=16, pixelCache=2, pixelsPerThread=2, filtersPerThread=4, preloadCases=32, numColors=3, scale=true, checkCaseBounds=false]" 
(2476): here

src/weight_acts.cu(1057): warning: expression has no effect
          detected during instantiation of "void conv_weight_acts_c_preload_pc_2_pt_2_f_4_r_32_c_3<B_Y,B_X,pixelCache,pixelsPerThread,filtersPerThread,preloadCases,numColors,scale,checkCaseBounds>(cudaTextureObject_t, cudaTextureObject_t, float *, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, float, float) [with B_Y=16, B_X=16, pixelCache=2, pixelsPerThread=2, filtersPerThread=4, preloadCases=32, numColors=3, scale=true, checkCaseBounds=false]" 
(2476): here

src/weight_acts.cu(1058): warning: expression has no effect
          detected during instantiation of "void conv_weight_acts_c_preload_pc_2_pt_2_f_4_r_32_c_3<B_Y,B_X,pixelCache,pixelsPerThread,filtersPerThread,preloadCases,numColors,scale,checkCaseBounds>(cudaTextureObject_t, cudaTextureObject_t, float *, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, float, float) [with B_Y=16, B_X=16, pixelCache=2, pixelsPerThread=2, filtersPerThread=4, preloadCases=32, numColors=3, scale=true, checkCaseBounds=false]" 
(2476): here

src/weight_acts.cu(1213): warning: expression has no effect
          detected during instantiation of "void conv_weight_acts_c_preload_pc_2_pt_4_f_3_r_32_c_3<B_Y,B_X,pixelCache,pixelsPerThread,filtersPerThread,preloadCases,numColors,scale,checkCaseBounds>(cudaTextureObject_t, cudaTextureObject_t, float *, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, float, float) [with B_Y=16, B_X=16, pixelCache=2, pixelsPerThread=4, filtersPerThread=3, preloadCases=32, numColors=3, scale=true, checkCaseBounds=false]" 
(2480): here

src/weight_acts.cu(1289): warning: expression has no effect
          detected during instantiation of "void conv_weight_acts_c_preload_pc_2_pt_4_f_3_r_32_c_3<B_Y,B_X,pixelCache,pixelsPerThread,filtersPerThread,preloadCases,numColors,scale,checkCaseBounds>(cudaTextureObject_t, cudaTextureObject_t, float *, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, float, float) [with B_Y=16, B_X=16, pixelCache=2, pixelsPerThread=4, filtersPerThread=3, preloadCases=32, numColors=3, scale=true, checkCaseBounds=false]" 
(2480): here

src/weight_acts.cu(1290): warning: expression has no effect
          detected during instantiation of "void conv_weight_acts_c_preload_pc_2_pt_4_f_3_r_32_c_3<B_Y,B_X,pixelCache,pixelsPerThread,filtersPerThread,preloadCases,numColors,scale,checkCaseBounds>(cudaTextureObject_t, cudaTextureObject_t, float *, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, float, float) [with B_Y=16, B_X=16, pixelCache=2, pixelsPerThread=4, filtersPerThread=3, preloadCases=32, numColors=3, scale=true, checkCaseBounds=false]" 
(2480): here

src/weight_acts.cu(1291): warning: expression has no effect
          detected during instantiation of "void conv_weight_acts_c_preload_pc_2_pt_4_f_3_r_32_c_3<B_Y,B_X,pixelCache,pixelsPerThread,filtersPerThread,preloadCases,numColors,scale,checkCaseBounds>(cudaTextureObject_t, cudaTextureObject_t, float *, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, float, float) [with B_Y=16, B_X=16, pixelCache=2, pixelsPerThread=4, filtersPerThread=3, preloadCases=32, numColors=3, scale=true, checkCaseBounds=false]" 
(2480): here

src/weight_acts.cu(1292): warning: expression has no effect
          detected during instantiation of "void conv_weight_acts_c_preload_pc_2_pt_4_f_3_r_32_c_3<B_Y,B_X,pixelCache,pixelsPerThread,filtersPerThread,preloadCases,numColors,scale,checkCaseBounds>(cudaTextureObject_t, cudaTextureObject_t, float *, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, float, float) [with B_Y=16, B_X=16, pixelCache=2, pixelsPerThread=4, filtersPerThread=3, preloadCases=32, numColors=3, scale=true, checkCaseBounds=false]" 
(2480): here

src/weight_acts.cu(1293): warning: expression has no effect
          detected during instantiation of "void conv_weight_acts_c_preload_pc_2_pt_4_f_3_r_32_c_3<B_Y,B_X,pixelCache,pixelsPerThread,filtersPerThread,preloadCases,numColors,scale,checkCaseBounds>(cudaTextureObject_t, cudaTextureObject_t, float *, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, float, float) [with B_Y=16, B_X=16, pixelCache=2, pixelsPerThread=4, filtersPerThread=3, preloadCases=32, numColors=3, scale=true, checkCaseBounds=false]" 
(2480): here

src/weight_acts.cu(1294): warning: expression has no effect
          detected during instantiation of "void conv_weight_acts_c_preload_pc_2_pt_4_f_3_r_32_c_3<B_Y,B_X,pixelCache,pixelsPerThread,filtersPerThread,preloadCases,numColors,scale,checkCaseBounds>(cudaTextureObject_t, cudaTextureObject_t, float *, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, float, float) [with B_Y=16, B_X=16, pixelCache=2, pixelsPerThread=4, filtersPerThread=3, preloadCases=32, numColors=3, scale=true, checkCaseBounds=false]" 
(2480): here

61 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00001ed4_00000000-6_weight_acts.cpp1.ii".
27 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00001ed5_00000000-6_filter_acts.cpp1.ii".
make: *** [obj/release/./src/weight_acts.cu.o] Error 2
make: *** [obj/release/./src/filter_acts.cu.o] Error 2
30 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00001ed3_00000000-6_img_acts.cpp1.ii".
make: *** [obj/release/./src/img_acts.cu.o] Error 2
--- cudaconvnet
build.sh: 59: cd: can't cd to cudaconvnet
--- make-data/pyext
build.sh: 61: cd: can't cd to make-data/pyext
```

BTW, I am using Cuda 6.0 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: which cuda version do you have?

Comment: nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2013 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jul_17_18:36:13_PDT_2013
Cuda compilation tools, release 5.5, V5.5.0

Comment: what does this command prints out? 
nvidia-smi

Comment: NVIDIA-SMI 331.62     Driver Version: 331.62